# Problem with showing a Facebook profile image in an ImageView

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I am trying to display the Facebook profile image using Glide in an ImageView once the user logs in, the problem is that Glide only loads the default image from Facebook, I have tried different ways but it always loads the same image by default.

[This is the image that Glide shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ceY5.jpg)

Here is my code:

onCreate method:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);

    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null){
        goLoginScreen();
    }else {
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        if (profile != null){
            displayProfileInfo(profile);
        }else{
            Profile.fetchProfileForCurrentAccessToken();
        }
    }
    return view;
}
```

displayProfileInfo method:

```
private void displayProfileInfo(Profile profile){
    String name = profile.getName();
    String photoUrl = profile.getProfilePictureUri(100,100).toString();

    txtviewUname.setText(name);
    Glide.with(getActivity()).load(photoUrl).into(profileImage);
}
```

Comment: What do u mean by Default picture ? have you followed the [API Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/)?

Comment: Can you show us an example of a "default image from Facebook"? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: print the photoUrl variable data in logcat when you receive the url then hit on the browser

Comment: @AlexMamo Hi, i updated the question with a screenshot, that's what i mean by the default image

Comment: Hi, i updated the question with a screenshot, when I put the url in the browser, it shows me the same image by default. So the problem is the image url? How can I get the correct url? @MuhammadAsad

Comment: Hi, i updated the question with a screenshot, that's what i mean by the default image @ADM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment:

> when I put the URL in the browser, it shows me the same image by default.

This means that the [getPhotoUrl()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#getPhotoUrl()) method that exists in the [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) class, returns an URL that points to a valid photo. However, that photo is added automatically by Facebook when the users decide **not** to add any photos to the profile. So if a user doesn't have any photos, the default photo will always be displayed. So when you try to read the photo that is associated to such an account, the default photo will be displayed.

Comment: Hi Alex, I solved the problem by updating the Facebook sdk and using the methods of the Profile class, when I use the getPhotoUrl() method of the FirebaseUser class, it returns the default image, even if the user has a profile image. Thanks for helping

Comment: Hey, Andre. Good to hear that you solved it.

Answer (score -1):

Use context, for exemple

> getContext()

or

> requireContext()

, if it is in Activity use only

> this

Glide use Context

Comment: hello, previously I had already tried with getContext(), it does not work, it seems that the problem is the url of the facebook image